# Add Password Generator on password protected page

Tags: plugin-development, pages, password, publish, core-modifications

I'm looking for add a password generator with 14 characters on the protected pages like in the picture. I search something like what is used when you create users but for page password.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to modify the post submit meta boxes with a filter.

But you can do that with JavaScript. This script will generate 10-12 random alphanumeric string and put it in the password field (if it is empty) when you click the *Password protected* radio button.

```
$('#visibility-radio-password').click(function () {
    // If there is no password
    var $password = $('#post_password')
    if ( !$password.val() ) {
        $password.val(Math.random().toString(36).slice(2));
    }
});
```

Here you can learn how to correctly add JS scripts to admin pages - https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts

Comment: Thanks. I add your code on file called admin.js and put it on folder called JS .  I also put this code on function.php  :  add_action('admin_init', 'custom_admin_js');
function custom_admin_js() {
    wp_register_script( 'admin-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/admin.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'admin-js' );
} .        But it does not work .  any idea?

Comment: Change the `admin_init` hook to `admin_enqueue_scripts`. And as 3rd parameter of `wp_register_script` add `array('jquery')` as this script depends on it.

Comment: Is it possible for you to put the correct full code?  Thanks a lot

Comment: Your admin.js file should look like this: https://pastebin.com/31BvVSEt And in `functions.php` you should have this included: https://pastebin.com/8jxBs5PL

Comment: Thanks a lot Greg36. I add your code on admin.js and functions.php but it does not work. if you have time can you try it on you wordpress installation and tell me please. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I tested it and it worked in my case. Go to any admin page, press F12 in Chrome, in the new window select Console tab and check if there are any errors related to the admin.js file. If there are none, open Sources tab from the tree on the left open your website address then wp-content > your-theme-name and look if the admin.js file is present there.

Comment: Hi Greg, I found the issue. I use beaver builder child-theme. when I put the mother theme it works, but when use the child-theme it's not work. Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: To make it work in child theme you need to have that `admin.js` file inside js folder in your child theme folder. Then in `functions.php` in your child theme add this: https://pastebin.com/cUZwKKPH

Comment: it works! thanks a lot. Have you an idea how to have a password with 16 characters : letters (lowercase and uppercase) number and special characters?

Comment: This `Math.random().toString()` is sort of a trick to generate a random string. To make it exactly 16 characters long have this in `admin.js` - https://pastebin.com/dKnUWhgn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69462/discussion-between-sampaii-and-greg36).